# place text over image whether it exists or not

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text over image if it exists in database or same location if it does not exist.

the Issue am facing is that if there is an image, the text goes beneath it and if it's not there, text goes on teh correct location as explained on the attached picture. 
code is below:

```
<div class="category">
    <img src="home.php?cat={$mc.categoryid}"/>
    <div class="title">
       <h2>Some text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
<style>
.category{
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px
}

.title {
   position: relative;
   top: 3px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSSeN.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both the image and the text have `position:absolute` and `.category` has `position:relative`, with the text's `z-index` higher than that of the image's.

Comment: The image doesn't need a `position:absolute` to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Give your container `category` a `position` of `relative`. Then give the `position` of `absolute` to `.title`. The `position:absolute` takes whatever it was assigned to out of the normal flow of content. The `position:relative;` on the container will keep the `position:absolute` elements inside of that space. But you can still move it to where you want. So if you want to have the `.title` appear in the bottom right, apply styles such as `right:0` and `bottom:0`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL9Q9/)

Answer (score -1):

There is more than one way of doing this.

Method 1. Bring the "title" outside of the "category" div like this:

```
<div class="category">
    <img src="home.php?cat={$mc.categoryid}"/>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
```

Method 2. Include the image inside another div and give a fixed width and height like this:

```
<div class="category">
    <div style="width:xx; height:yy;">
       <img src="home.php?cat={$mc.categoryid}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
       <h2>Some text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above, you use your own values for xx and yy depending on how much you want to allocate for the image. Of course it doesn't have to be inline CSS. You can give it another class.

Comment: Taking `.title` out of the normal flow would cause the text to always be below, when he wants the text to always be above the picture

Comment: @CodyGuldner If you took the effort to understand his question, his "CORRECT POSITION" IS BELOW the image. So I believe I have answered the question. And with an elementary knowledge of CSS or html, one should know that if you want the title to be above the image, simply moving the containing div to the top would fix it. Well one can argue again but you see that's why I gave the options.